# Is there a way to have a RichTextBox's Paragraph Style set from a StaticResource from a ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I noticed this popular method exists for removing the margin of the paragraphs in a regular RichTextBox:

```html
<RichTextBox>
  <RichTextBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
  </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

However, I wonder if there is a way to have that style in a ResourceDictionary and then use it for the RichTextBox's Paragraph as a referenced StaticResource.

If not, what prevents it? I have only found a way to set it as a default style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. It should be pretty straight-forward:

**Dictionary1.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="pStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Usage:**

```
<RichTextBox>
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph Style="{StaticResource pStyle}">
            <Run Text="some text..." />
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking. The default style is the only one I needed for the reason I wanted it (for automatically appended paragraphs, not explicitly) and since I already knew about the default style method I shouldn't have asked the question. But since this is technically an accurate answer for the question, I'll upvote and accept in case it helps any beginner in the future.

Comment: Actually, I might be looking for a templated method for automatically appended paragraphs, but oh well it doesn't matter much and I haven't reached that part of the book yet.